# How are these rack and mudguard holders named?

Tags: parts, terminology

How are these parts holding the rack and the mudguards named in English? There are some pictures on the web featuring "parts of the bicycle" but they are not depicted there with names. This image is the cropped fragment taken from [Wikipedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:2018-06-19_(139)_KTM_Bicycle_at_Bahnhof_Herzogenburg.jpg).

[image]

Comment: Mudguard stays.

Comment: @JoeK that's an answer.  Okay yes its a short answer, but it's the correct answer.  Please post that as an answer.

Comment: Actually no, this would be best answered in the Terminology Glossary at https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/  because its not there already.

Comment: I have looked into this super question and yes, understand. Assuming the parts are really named the "stays", unless anybody else does, I myself will put the answer there.